# Executing a function in a loop in javascript asynchronously- where to place defer.resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, sails.js

I come from java/python background and new to javascript. I need to create a product list with the description of its children as well included in a jsonarray.

parent_list:

```
[{ children: [ 100714813, 100712694 ],
  sp: '89.10',
  weight: '1 ltr',
  pack_type: 'Carton',
  brand: 'Real',
  p_desc: 'Fruit Power Juice - Orange' }]
```

Now for every parent I need to again iteratively fetch the children details by connecting to the database and finally have the result consolidated in a single jsonarray. But when I execute the below code, the control doesn't wait for fetching the children data( which makes sense as its being called asynchronously!), the result I get is a jsonarray that contains data only for the parents that have no children.

```
exports.productDetailsQuery = function(options) {

    var AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE = '';  
    var AEROSPIKE_SET = 'products';
    var PD_KEY_VERSION_NUMBER = '1';

    var defer = sails.Q.defer();

    var results = options.results;
    var parent_list = [];
    var finalData = [];

    var productKeys = results.map(
        function(x){
            return {
                ns: AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE,
                set: AEROSPIKE_SET,
                key: "pd.v" + PD_KEY_VERSION_NUMBER + '.' + 'c' + options.city_id + '.' + x.sku.toString()
            }
        }
    );

    var status = require('aerospike').status;
    var breakException = {};

    // Read the batch of products.
    sails.aerospike.batchGet(productKeys, function (err, results) {
        if (err.code === status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                switch (results[i].status) {
                    case status.AEROSPIKE_OK:
                        parent_list.push(results[i].record);
                        break;
                    case status.AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND:
                        console.log("NOT_FOUND - ", results[i].keys);
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("ERR - %d - ", results[i].status, results[i].keys);
                }
            }
            parent_list.forEach(function(parent){
                var children = parent['children'];
                console.log(children)
                if(children){
                    var childKeys = children.map(function(child){
                        return {
                            ns: AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE,
                            set: AEROSPIKE_SET,
                            key: "pd.v" + PD_KEY_VERSION_NUMBER + '.' + 'c' + options.city_id + '.' + child.toString()
                        }
                    });
                    sails.aerospike.batchGet(childKeys, function(err, childData){
                        if(err.code === status.AEROSPIKE_OK){
                            console.log('this called')
                            var entry = {};
                            entry['primary_prod'] = parent;
                            entry['variants'] = childData;
                            finalData.push(entry);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    var entry = {};
                    entry['primary_prod'] = parent;
                    finalData.push(entry);
                }
            });
            defer.resolve(finalData);
        } else {
            defer.reject(err);
        }
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

I need finalData to be like:

```
[{"primary_prod":{ children: [ 100714813, 100712694 ],
  sp: '89.10',
  weight: '1 ltr',
  pack_type: 'Carton',
  brand: 'Real',
  p_desc: 'Fruit Power Juice - Orange' },
"variants":[{child_data},{child_data}]}, ...........]
```

Would really appreciate any help as to how to make it work.Is there a specific pattern to handle such cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically finallyData has values only from the else{} block of if(children){}. How can I ensure that the finalData is not returned before all the running processes in if(children){} get completed.

Comment: What parts of your code are actually asynchronous? You should create an own deferred/promise for each asynchronous task, and put the deferred as close to the call as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is along the right lines but only the outer `batchGet()` is promisified. Because there's no attempt to promisify the inner `batchGet()`, it doesn't contribute to the finally returned promise.

Your overall pattern might be something like this ...

```
exports.productDetailsQuery = function(options) {
    return sails.aerospike.batchGetAsync(...).then(results) {
        var promises = results.filter(function(res) {
            // Filter out any results that are not `AEROSPIKE_OK`
            ...
        }).map(function(parent) {
            // Map the filtered results to an array of promises
            return sails.aerospike.batchGetAsync(...).then(function(childData) {
                ...
            });
        });
        // Aggregate the array of promises into a single promise that will resolve when all the individual promises resolve, or will reject if any one of the individual promises rejects.
        return sails.Q.all(promises);
    });
}
```

... where `batchGetAsync()` is a promisified version of `batchGet()`.

The fully fleshed-out the code will be longer but can be kept reasonably concise, and readable, by first defining a couple of utility functions. You might end up with something like this  :

```
// utility function for making a "key" object
function makeKey(obj) {
    return {
        ns: '', //AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE
        set: 'products', //AEROSPIKE_SET
        key: 'pd.v1.c' + options.city_id + '.' + obj.toString()
    }
}

// promisified version of batchGet()
function batchGetAsync(obj) {
    var defer = sails.Q.defer();
    batchGet(obj, function(err, results) {
        if(err.code === status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
            defer.resolve(results);
        } else {
            defer.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise; 
}

var status = require('aerospike').status;

// Main routine
exports.productDetailsQuery = function(options) {
    return batchGetAsync(options.results.map(makeKey)).then(results) {
        var promises = results.filter(function(res) {
            if (res.status === status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
                return true;
            } else if(status.AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND) {
                console.log("NOT_FOUND - ", res.keys);
            } else {
                console.log("ERR - %d - ", res.status, res.keys);
            }
            return false;
        }).map(function(parent) {
            var entry = { 'primary_prod': parent },
                children = parent['children'];
            if(children) {
                return batchGetAsync(children.map(makeKey)).then(function(childData) {
                    entry.variants = childData;
                    return entry;
                });
            } else {
                return entry;
            }
        });
        return sails.Q.all(promises);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

With the new ES6 plus async stuff and babel its simpler.  You can `npm i -g babel` `npm i babel-runtime` then compile and run the following with `babel test.js --optional runtime --stage 2 | node`:

```
import {inspect} from 'util';                                   

let testData = [                                                
  { id: 0, childIds: [1,2]},                                    
  { id: 1, childIds:[] },                                       
  { id: 2, childIds:[] }                                        
];                                                              

function dbGet(ids) {                                           
  return new Promise( r=> {                                     
    r(ids.map((id) => { return testData[id];}));                
  });                                                           
}                                                               

async function getChildren(par) {                               
  let children = await dbGet(par.childIds);                     
  par.children = children;                                      
}                                                               

async function getAll(parentIds) {                              
  let parents = await dbGet(parentIds);                         
  for (let p of parents) {                                      
    await getChildren(p);                                       
  }                                                             
  return parents;                                               
}                                                               

async function test() {                                         
  var results = await getAll([0]);                              
  console.log(inspect(results,{depth:3}));                      
}                                                               

test().then(f=>{}).catch( e=> {console.log('e',e)});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the query- really appreciate it!